# Vertical line in table columns

Tags: tables

In the following table I want to separate the columns:

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
l
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering}X
>{\centering\arraybackslash}X
}
 & \multicolumn{13}{c}{Exercise}\\
\cmidrule{2-14}
{Name} & 1(i) & 1(ii) & 1(iii) &2(i) & 2(ii) & 2(iii) & 2(iv) & 2(v) & 2(vi)& 3(i) & 3(ii)& 3(iii)& 4 \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
 & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
 & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
 & & & & & & & & & & & & &
\end{tabularx}
```

In tabularx doesn't seem to work to write {c|c...|c} afterwards. I would be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: I think you mean vertical line not horizontal? just place a `|` after each `X`

Comment: Since you're using the line-drawing macros of the `booktabs` package, you shouldn't be drawing any vertical rules. Really.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is not entirely clear how your table should look. Like this:

[image]

The table code with use of the `tabularray` package is simple:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry} % added, your page layout is unknow
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
\begin{tblr}{vlines,
             colsep=3pt,
             colspec = {l *{13}{X[c]}}
             }
    \toprule
\SetCell[r=2]{l}    Name
    &   \SetCell[c=13]{c}   Exercise    \\
    \midrule
    & 1(i) & 1(ii) & 1(iii) 
    & 2(i) & 2(ii) & 2(iii) & 2(iv) & 2(v) & 2(vi)
    & 3(i) & 3(ii) & 3(iii) & 4         \\
    \hline
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   &   \\
    \bottomrule
\end{tblr}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Or you like to have horizontal line between each row? In this case to table preamble you need to add `hline{4-Y}=solid,`, i.e. it should be:

```
\begin{tblr}{hline{4-Y}=solid, vlines,
             colsep=3pt,
             colspec = {l *{13}{X[c]}}
             }
```

In this case table is:

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much! This is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 4):

Since there's no indication that automatic line breaking is needed in *any* of the cells in the data columns, I'd use a `tabular*` environment with the `c` column type for all data columns, instead of a `tabularx` environment.

Much of the information in the header cells is currently rather repetitive, with the labels "1" and "3" occurring three times each and the label "2" occuring six [6!] times. One way to reduce the resulting visual clutter is to provide more hierarchical structure in the table's header, along the lines pursued in the following example.

With these adjustments in place, there is no need for any vertical lines, further cutting down on clutter.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[ht]
\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt} % make LaTeX figure out permissible amount of intercolumn whitespace
\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}} l *{13}{c} }
\toprule
Name & \multicolumn{13}{c}{Exercise}\\
\cmidrule{2-14}
& \multicolumn{3}{c}{1} & \multicolumn{6}{c}{2} & \multicolumn{3}{c}{3} & 4 \\
\cmidrule{2-4}  \cmidrule{5-10} \cmidrule{11-13} 
& (i) & (ii) & (iii) & (i) & (ii) & (iii) & (iv) & (v) & (vi) & (i) & (ii) & (iii) &  \\
\midrule
 & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
 & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
 & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
 & & & & & & & & & & & & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! Also a very nice way to do.