# Columns overlapping

Tags: tables

I asked the following question:
[Horizontal line in table](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/642263/horizontal-line-in-table)

Is there any way to get that the columns are not overlapping, so can I somehow change the width?

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{
l|
>{\centering}X|
>{\centering}X|
>{\centering}X|
>{\centering}X|
>{\centering}X|
>{\centering}X|
>{\centering}X|
>{\centering}X|
>{\centering}X|
>{\centering}X|
>{\centering}X|
>{\centering}X|
>{\centering\arraybackslash}X
}
 & \multicolumn{13}{c}{Exercise}\\
\cmidrule{2-14}
{Name} & 1(i) & 1(ii) & 1(iii) &2(i) & 2(ii) & 2(iii) & 2(iv) & 2(v) & 2(vi)& 3(i) & 3(ii)& 3(iii)& 4 \\\hline
 & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
 & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
 & & & & & & & & & & & & &\\
 & & & & & & & & & & & & &
\end{tabularx}
```

Comment: You could squeeze a bit more in if you suppress the spacing between the columns with, e.g., `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{0pt}` (and also `\noindent`) before the table. But you might need to do something else to make things fit comfortably. There just isn't quite enough space without changing the font size or rearranging the content.

Comment: You could save some space using c columns and tabular*, assuming all your data fit in one line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not enough space for these headers, and it could be worse depending on of the content of the following rows. In these cases, it is better to use `tabulary` instead of `tabularx`, so each L,C,R, o r J column try to take the best width according to the contents of the column, not only of the header.

The vertical rules are always some to avoid but in this case are just making the lack of space worse, so I show an alternative use of the rules.

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabulary,booktabs,lipsum,parskip}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\begin{tabulary}{\textwidth}{@{}lCCCCCCCCCCCCC@{}}\toprule
 & \multicolumn{13}{c}{Exercise}\\\cmidrule{2-14}
{Name} & 1(i) & 1(ii) & 1(iii) &2(i) & 2(ii) & 2(iii) & 2(iv) & 2(v) & 2(vi)& 3(i) & 3(ii)& 3(iii)& 4 \\
\cmidrule(r){1-1}
\cmidrule(rl){2-2}
\cmidrule(rl){3-3}
\cmidrule(rl){4-4}
\cmidrule(rl){5-5}
\cmidrule(rl){6-6}
\cmidrule(rl){7-7}
\cmidrule(rl){8-8}
\cmidrule(rl){9-9}
\cmidrule(rl){10-10}
\cmidrule(rl){11-11}
\cmidrule(rl){12-12}
\cmidrule(rl){13-13}
\cmidrule(l){14-14}
 Foo & a & b & c & d & e & f & g  & h & i & j & k & l & m\\
 Bah  & nn & oo& pp& qq& rr& ss& tt& uu& vv& ww& xx& yy & zz\\
 Baz  & nnn & ooo& ppp& qqq& rrr& srs& ttt& uuu& vvv& www& xxx& yyy & zzz\\\bottomrule
\end{tabulary}
\end{document}
```

Nonetheless, consider reduce the font size and/or redesign the table, for instance, to some like this:

[image: mwe]